# PHP/Curl progress while downloading

Tags: php, jquery, percentage

I'm using a system curl command via php to download a file. That is all working fine, but I'm now trying to show some progress as it's downloaded.

The curl command and php called is:

```
$a = popen("cd user; curl -O -# remote.server.com/filename.tar.gz 2>&1", 'r');

ob_flush();flush();
while($b = fgets($a, 64)) {
    ob_flush();flush();
        if (preg_match('~\b(error|fail|unknown)\b~i',$b)) {
            echo "error^$b";
            exit;
        }
        echo str_replace('#','',$b);
       ob_flush();flush();
}
pclose($a);
```

This is called using ajax and the output is displayed in a div:

```
var last_response_len = false;
        $.ajax(url, {
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e)
                {
                    var this_response, response = e.currentTarget.response;
                    if(last_response_len === false)
                    {
                        this_response = response;
                        last_response_len = response.length;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this_response = response.substring(last_response_len);
                        last_response_len = response.length;
                    }
                    $(upg).show();
                    console.log(this_response)
                    var count = this_response.match(/%/g);
                    if (count !== null && count.length != 2) $(msg).html(this_response);
               }
            }
        })
```

This works but the results showin in the `msg div` are not consistent.
I may get :

```
1%
5%
12.1%
12.5% 13.2%
14.2%
5.3%
16.7%
```

I get partial results ie: `5.3% instead of 15.3%`, I get multiple results within the same output ie: `12.5% & 13.2%`

is there anyway to standardise this so I only get 0% through to 100% ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the php str_replace to

```
str_replace(['#', ' '], '', $b);
```

Then you get only the percentage, without the preceding blanks, which you can just insert to the container without editing.

Example:
https://3v4l.org/OGWqU

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd actually worked it out, but your answer is virtually the same as what I've come up with. The only other thing I've added is to only echo the results if there are 5 characters.  This results is a slight pause and then the process starts at `10.0%`  This works well for when there are a couple of enters where a digit is missing.